# How to perform segue from inside UIView

Tags: ios, swift, segue

How can a prepare a segue properly from inside a UIView ***NOT*** UIViewController

My UIViewController has a container view and inside that container view has a button.

```
class myInnerView: UIView {
    ...
    func myButton(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer){
        //calling a perform segue from another UIViewController does not recognize the SegueID
        //ViewController().self.showProfile(self.id) -- DOES NOT WORK
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
    func showProfile(id: String){
        ...
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toViewProfile", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your view should not handle a button tap. That should be handled by the *controller*. (This is why it is called "controller", while the `UIView` is called "view").

[MVC as described by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html).

Comment: Is it legal to set an action on a UIView that targets a UIViewController?

Comment: It certainly is not recommended practice. The view should display stuff, not fire view controllers.

Answer (score -1):

If the button is a subview of your view controller's view, you should be able to drag an IBAction onTouchUpInside from the button to your view controller. You can then initiate the segue from that method.

Comment: Could you please show with some code how to "initiale the segue from that methode"?
Because i am try to override prepare for segue but it never get called

Answer (score -1):

One of the solution is to add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your button but from inside the `UIViewController` :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myInnerView = myInnerView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleTapGesture))
        self.myInnerView.myButton.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func handleTapGesture(){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toViewProfile", sender: nil)
    }
}

class myInnerView: UIView {
    // make outlet of your button so you can add the tapGestureRecognizer from your ViewController and thats all
    @IBOutlet public weak var myButton: UIButton!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to tap gesture for view to navigate

```
let customView = myInnerView()
let gestureRec = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.someAction (_:)))
myView.addGestureRecognizer(customView)


func someAction(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController")
    self.present(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    // swift 2
    // self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```